# barely any options being shown within blender

Tags: interface

ive just started using blender, so be patient with me if this is a simple fix.

i recently got blender for 3d modelling, and in all tutorials ive seen, almost none of the options shown appear in my version of blender, my current issue is with the sidebar menu that is toggleable with the keybind "n" showing about a tenth of the amount of options that should be there.

is my blender in some sort of simplified mode?

another issue is that right click is supposed to allow you to add meshes, but this functionality is also removed

example of issue:

how my sidebar appears

[image: the bad]

how ive seen it appear

[image: the good]

all help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The user interface of Blender was updated in the 2.80 version. Many tutorials are using an older version of Blender which looks a bit different. However the features are still there in Blender 2.8x*, just in slightly different places or on a different shortcut. I'd recommend to watch the [Blender Fundamentals 2.8](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6) for an introduction to the new user interface and Blender in general.

<sub>* There are some exceptions, e.g. the Blender Internal render engine has been replaced with Eevee and the Blender Game Engine has been removed.</sub>

The options you're looking for in the sidebar are located in the *View* tab. There you'll find the properties for the *Clip Start*, *End* and *3D Cursor*.

[image: View tab]

Meshes can be created either through the *Add* menu or by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

[image: Add object]